# How to change tick's text with ordinal axis

Tags: dc.js

I have chart with next properties:

```
barChart
       .width(width)
       .height(height)
       .dimension(dim)
       .group(group)
       .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
       .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

My axis tick looks like "ZZxBob", "PxBob"

How to use split function by 'x' to each tick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axes are generated entirely by D3.

You can use [`chart.xAxis()`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#xAxis__anchor) to retrieve the x axis object, and then [`axis.tickFormat()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickFormat) to change the way it's displayed.

So, e.g. to display the part before x:

```
barChart.xAxis()
    .tickFormat(function(l) { return l.split('x')[0]; })
```