# Change labels for bar chart dc.js

Tags: bar-chart, dc.js

[image]

I want to display months in dc.js barchart X - axis as Jan, Feb , Mar and so on.

Below are the code details -

```
  var monthlyDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        var monthName = getMonth(d.month);
        return +d.month;
    });
```

I have tried changing this to -

```
    var monthDimLabels = ndx.dimension(function(d) {            
    var monthName = getMonth(d.month);
        return monthName;
    });

function getMonth(month) 
{ 
return ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"][parseInt(month)-1] }
```

But still only month numbers are visible in X-axis

Json structure -

```
var data = [ {
        dt : '28/01/2018',
        temp : 20,

    }, {
        dt : '16/02/2018',
        temp : 45,

    }
```

Can someone please suggest how to change the label name similar to

```
 heatmapChart.colsLabel(function(d) {
        return d;
    });
```

But colsLabel and rowsLabel is not supported in BarChart. Any help is appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag to ask questions about the charting library; [dc] is a classic unix calculator utility. I missed this question as a result. Fixing now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change tick's text with ordinal axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526943/how-to-change-ticks-text-with-ordinal-axis)

Comment: It's really a d3 question, which is why you don't find a dc.js API for it.